# Which Endpoint should represent a trhreeway many to many Relationship with non related elements as well

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

It's difficult to sintetize the question into one line, but I hope I can explain myself better here:

I've got the following model:

**Users**

- id

**Messages**

- id

**Tags**

- id

**UsersMessagesCategories**

- id
- userId
- messageId
- tagId

`Tags` are **NOT** created by the `user`, available `tags` are created via admin panel.

I want to make an endpoint that returns the *avaliable* `tags` for a `message` but with the ones that are already associated, by that `user`, to that `message` **flagged**.

I can't seem to find a Rest standard way to make this.

PS: Just to make it clear, I want:

```
{
   tags:[
     {id: 1, associated: false},
     {id: 2, associated: true},
     {id: 3, associated: false}
   ]
}
```

Or maybe the way is:

```
{
   tags:[
     associated:[
       {id: 2},
       {id: 1}
     ],
     unassociated: [
       {id: 3}
     ]
   ]
}
```

I also don't know if it should be returned by (I guess this is the one):

`/users/1/messages/1/tags`

or by:

`/tags`

or even by:

`messages/1/tags`

Edit: Changed the endpoints so the URI is built with plural names.

Comment: What is *communication*? What's the difference between *communication* and *UsersMessagesCategories*?

Comment: Typo, communication and message are exactly the same. I changed it to be consistent.

Comment: First, there is no such thing as restful-url IMO - it's just a URI. Next, best practices often use resource-names in plural. To your actual question, can a tag exist without a message? If so it's valid for being a top-level resource, if not then it should be a sub-resource of messages. BTW: I do not like a counter as ID as if you move items or insert new ones in between to which resource ID: 2 is actually pointing? Therefore better use some UUIDs as ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with something like `/tags?user=X&message=Y`? As I understood tags are not direct children of messages or users, so no need to be direct children in the URL pattern.
REST doesn't define a real pattern to access resources, so you can use it more query-like with GET parameters like I wrote or you can have a more tree-like structure as you proposed.
The best thing you can do is to make every REST resource of your project accessible via a similar URL pattern, to make it more user friendly.

The first solution you proposed to format in JSON the results is the better one in my opinion

```
{
    tags:
    [
        {id: 1, associated: false},
        {id: 2, associated: true},
        {id: 3, associated: false}
    ]
}
```

but also this depends a lot on how you modeled the others REST services of your project. If you want you can return also the user which associate the tag with the message to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for (mind the *plural names*):

```
/users/:user-id/messages/:message-id/tags
```

Assuming a tag can exist without a message, you also could support an endpoint to return all the available tags:

```
/tags
```